# How to support run-time shader modification/code execution?

Tags: shaders, procedural-generation, code-reflection

I would like to create an educational game, part of which involves allowing the user to modify code for procedurally generating geometry on the CPU and modify shader code and see the changes they make reflected in real-time.

Unlike [How can I create a shader at runtime in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068364/how-can-i-create-shader-in-runtime-in-unity), I can't use a workaround with if statements, since one of the learning goals is to learn how to code shaders/procedural geometry, and I want users to be able to enter genuinely arbitrary code (ideally sandboxed) to explore the space of possibilities.

My current workflow uses javascript, THREE.js, and GLSL (through webGL), which can certainly manage this kind of process, but I'm considering learning to use a large game engine (such as Unity or Unreal) to take advantage of the conveniences they offer (and so I can learn how to use a large game engine).

How can I allow runtime shader authoring in the context of a larger game engine?

Comment: Unity has deprecated runtime compilation of shaders. You can use native plugin to do that, A bit cumbersome in my opinion: See [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/runtime-shader-compilation.87085/) and [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-compute-shader-at-runtime.451571/)

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is about Godot.** Since Godot games are running on the same core as the editor, they can do almost everything the editor can do. This also means that powerful modding and meta-programming is possible with Godot.

---

### Godot

This is quite an advanced topic to be the entry point for Godot. I don't think I can make a proper introduction to the engine here, so please pick up a [tutorial](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/community/tutorials.html). Yet some concepts are going to be necessary for the answer, so I feel compelled to provide a quick and dirty explanation of some of Godot idiosyncrasy, mainly similarities and differences with other engines.

First of all, there is an `SceneTree`, it has `Node`s, and each node can have a `Script` attached. Some kinds of `Node` include `Viewport`, `Camera`, `RigidBody`, `MeshInstance`, `ImmediateGeometry`, and so on.

You can have serialized branches (serialized `Node`s including children), and to that we refer as "scene". So you can instance a "scene" inside the `SceneTree`. And you can also instance a "scene" inside another "scene", because it all one `SceneTree`. So there is no "prefab"/"scene" distinction.

Also, Godot is not component based, instead of adding components to a `Node`, you add specialized `Node`s as children. Thus, again, it is all one `SceneTree`.

*Well, we are actually going to challenge the idea that there is only one `SceneTree` in this answer. So, let us say it is all - usually - one `SceneTree`.*

It is also useful to be aware of `Resources`. `Resources` are `Objects` that Godot knows how to serializase and deserialize. So, an "scene" is a `Resource`, of type `PackedScene` to be precise. `Script`s are also `Resource`s, and so are meshes and so on.

*By the way, I've been told that `Resource`s are similar to "ScriptableObjects" or "DataAssets", but more versatile.*

Godot has both reference types and value types. All reference types ultimately inherit from `Object`. Among them, some are reference counted, which inherit from `Reference`. The `Node` does not inherit form `Reference`. Instead they are manually freed. Which also means you could have a reference to a freed `Node`, which is not a `null` pointer. You can check with `is_instance_valid`.

A `GDScript` script is a `GDScript` class. Or to put it another way, `GDScript` scripts can inherit from other `GDScript` scripts. They can also inherit from built-in classes. If we don't specify, they inherit from `Reference`. So all `GDScript` scripts ultimately inherit from some built-in type.

Finally, when we attach a script to a `Node`, we need a script that inherits from the class of the `Node`. In fact, when we call `new` on a script (and I remind you that the script is class as far as other scripts are concerned), Godot will instance an `Object` of the type the built-in type the script ultimately inherits from and attach the script to it.

---

### Sandboxing?

Godot does not have proper sandboxing… And by that I mean there is no permission system or similar that restricts what the code can do. So the fact that Godot lets you do so much at runtime is a double edged sword.

However, I want to point out that you can create a separate `SceneTree` from the one you get by default. It is easy, actually:

```
var scene_tree := SceneTree.new()
```

We can call `init` on it:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    scene_tree.init()
```

*The `_ready` function will run when the `Node` and dependencies has been loaded in the `SceneTree`, I mean, the main one in this case… The one in which the `Node` with script we are talking about is.*

And with that the secondary `SceneTree` will start rendering over the main one. You can disable that if you don't want it to, with:

```
scene_tree.get_root().set_update_mode(Viewport.UPDATE_DISABLED)
```

*Be aware that the `root` of the `SceneTree` is a `Viewport`.*

Or if you prefer to have both, perhaps we can split the screen. The following code will set then side by side:

```
func resize() -> void:
    var window_size := OS.window_size
    var half_window_size := Vector2(window_size.x * 0.5, window_size.y)
    var left := Rect2(Vector2.ZERO, half_window_size)
    var right := Rect2(Vector2(half_window_size.x, 0.0), half_window_size)
    scene_tree.get_root().set_attach_to_screen_rect(right)
    get_tree().get_root().set_attach_to_screen_rect(left)
```

We want to run that code every time the window/screen resizes, so let us connect it to the `"screen_resized"` signal (and by signal I mean what you would call an "event"):

```
func _ready() -> void:
    scene_tree.init()
    get_tree().connect("screen_resized", self, "resize")
```

And while we are at it, make sure to call it at least once:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    scene_tree.init()
    get_tree().connect("screen_resized", self, "resize")
    res
```

*Be aware that this is not a typical split screen. Usually when we split the screen we want to render the same `SceneTree` on each side, perhaps form a different `Camera`. But we are not doing that here. Instead here we are rendering two entirely different `SceneTree`s. Of which, one controls the other.*

---

You can change the the scene of the `SceneTree`, for example:

```
scene_tree.change_scene("res://scenes/test/scene.tscn")
```

And we need to call into the secondary `SceneTree` each frame:

```
func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    scene_tree.idle(delta)

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    scene_tree.iteration(delta)
```

*The `_process` method will run each graphics frame. And the `_physics_process` will run each physics frame. You can establish the rate of physics frames in Project Settings.*

Finally call `scene_tree.finish()` when you are done with it.

I remind you that this secondary `scene_tree` is like the main one. It has a `root` and you can add `Node`s to it.

Then you can put all the stuff made at runtime in that other `SceneTree`. It does not give you control over what that code can do (because, again, no proper sandboxing). *So it can still make network requests, mess with the file system and stuff like that.* <strike>But it will be isolated form your own (the code on the secondary `SceneTree` does not have a way to get a reference to the main one).</strike>

**ERRATA**: There is a way: [`Engine.get_main_loop`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_engine.html#class-engine-method-get-main-loop) will give you the default [`MainLoop`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_mainloop.html) which is the `SceneTree` (the `SceneTree` class extends `MainLoop`). By the way, you can change the main loop from project settings, under Application -> Run -> Main Loop Type.

---

Ultimately you would probably want to parse the code from the user. This will allow you to provide pretty printing, and also making sure it does not call what it should not. You can start with the [GDScript reference grammar](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/file_formats/gdscript_grammar.html). The documentation does not include the equivalent for the [shading language](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/shader_reference/shading_language.html#doc-shading-language), however it is basically GLSL.

---

### Creating shaders at runtime

*I'll point out that Godot has `VisualShader` but the UI to create them is not included in games. You could make your own UI for them (Based on `GraphEdit` and `GraphNode`). But this answer will cover text based shaders instead.*

To create a shader in runtime in Godot, we can follow the following approach:

1. Create a new `ShaderMaterial` object:

   ```
   var shader_material := ShaderMaterial.new()
   ```
2. Create a new `Shader` object:

   ```
   var shader = Shader.new()
   ```
3. Then set the shader code for the shader:

   ```
   shader.code = """
   shader_type spatial;
   render_mode unshaded;

   void fragment()
   {
       ALBEDO = vec3(UV, 0.0);
   }
   """
   ```

   *Here I'm using `"""` for a multiline string literal. The example is an a spatial shader (so one you would use for a `MeshInstance` (3D)) that output the UV coordinates as color.*
4. Set the shader to the shader material:

   ```
   shader_material.shader = shader
   ```
5. And set the shader material to where you need it:

   ```
   $MeshInstance.set("material/0", shader_material)
   ```

   *Here it will be the first material (`0`) of the mesh.*

   *Oh, by the way, the `$` syntax is used in GDScript to reference a child `Node` by name.*

Just because you have already set the material does not mean you cannot replace the code. So, if I have already set a shader material, I can just replace the code, no hassle:

```
var shader_material = $MeshInstance.get("material/0")
shader_material.shader.code = """
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

void fragment()
{
    ALBEDO = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
"""
```

*This shader outputs pure yellow.*

Beyond that, if you want to allow users to write shader code, you could provide a text editor, take what the write, and perhaps do some string manipulation before setting it such as shown above.

Caution:

- Make sure you have a `ShaderMaterial` with a `Shader` before you try to modify its code, otherwise you are going to get an error.
- If the code is invalid you will also get an error.

In this error conditions you are going to get the default material. So they are not fatal. However, I haven't found a good way to detect them from GDScript. What the editor does is output the errors to the console. We could use logging (you can configure it on project settings, it is enabled by default) and monitor the logs, but that is not practical at all.

- When the shader compiles (when it is first seen), Godot may skip a frame. Godot 3.4.5 (currently in beta) should allow for async compilation of shaders.

---

### Creating meshes at runtime

The simplest way to generate a mesh at runtime is using a `Node` of type `ImmediateGeometry`. Its usage is similar to old school OpenGL's immediate mode.

For example, this would draw a segment (I'm assuming this is running in a script attached to the `ImmediateGeometry`):

```
clear()
begin(Mesh.PRIMITIVE_LINES)
add_vertex(Vector3.ZERO)
add_vertex(Vector3.FORWARD)
end()
```

However, despite the name and the similarity to the immediate mode, it is actually creating a mesh under the scenes. Which is why we need to call `clear` to reset it, and also why this code does not have to be in `_process` or any particular method. In fact, the coordinates of the vertex are local, and you can position the `ImmediateGeometry` like any other node.

We can, of course, make a triangle mesh with `Mesh.PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLES` instead of `Mesh.PRIMITIVE_LINES`.

And we can set:

- Vertex color with `set_color`.
- Normal with `set_normal`.
- Tangent and binormal with `set_tangent`. It takes a `Plane`, the normal of the plane is the tangent. The distance to the plane is the scale of the binormal (you probably want to pass `1.0`).
- UV with `set_uv`.
- UV2 with `set_uv2`.

You can assign a material to the `ImmediateGeometry` by setting its `material_override`. If you need more than one material, or some other features, we need to move to `SurfaceTool`.

---

To use `SurfaceTool`, create an instance:

```
var surface_tool := SurfaceTool.new()
```

Then we use `SurfaceTool` pretty similar to `ImmediateGeometry` above. So we can call `begin`, `add_vertex` and so on. Furthermore, you can set a material with `set_material` and even define bones and weights. Taking full advantage of `SurfaceTool` is beyond me, but…

What you are making is a *surface*. You are going to add these surfaces to a mesh. So have a mesh:

```
var mesh := ArrayMesh.new()
```

And then add the surface to the mesh:

```
surface_tool.commit(mesh)
```

Do that for as many surfaces as you need. Each surface can have its own material.

---

You may also be interested in `MeshDataTool` which provides some capacity to query and edit existing meshes (instead of authoring new ones).

---

### Creating and running scripts at runtime

*Godot also support visual scripting ("blueprints" style), but similar to what happens with `VisualShader`, the UI to create them is not included in games. But we have text based scripting, and that is what I'll talk about.*

You can create that a script in runtime too. Create a `GDScript` object:

```
var script:= GDScript.new()
```

Then set its `source_code`:

```
script.source_code = """
extends Node

func method() -> void:
    print("hello")
"""
```

*Yes, you could also read the `source_code` of existing GDScript scripts. On a similar note, you could have the script created at runtime inherit from another script.*

Then reload it… This time checking if it went OK is readily available:

```
if OK != script.reload():
    print("Error loading script")
```

And now you could attach it to an `Object` (e.g. a `Node`) with `set_script`. Or you can instance it directly, and use it:

```
if script.can_instance():
    var instance := script.new() as Node
    instance.method() # should print "hello"
```

---

I also want to mention `Expression` which will let you execute - as the name suggest - an expression.

Start by creating the `Expression` object:

```
var expression := Expression.new()
```

Then parse the string expression:

```
var parameters:PoolStringArray = ["p"]
if OK != expression.parse("2 + p", parameters):
    print(expression.get_error_text())
```

In this case the expression will have one parameter `"p"` which we need to pass when we want to execute it.

And, of course, execute it:

```
var argument := [5]
var result = expression.execute(arguments, null, true)
if not expression.has_execute_failed():
    print(result) # should print 7
```

The arguments are passed to the parameters according to their position in the array.

The `null` I'm passing is the `self` reference. And the `true` is enabling error output.

So `Expression` can be a way to execute something that might fail and check if it failed. *And, no, it does not work for the shader, as the error happens when Godot compiles it not when we set its code.*

Answer (score 0):

[Polygonjs](https://polygonjs.com) may be interesting for this situation. It is nowhere near as complete as Unity or Unreal, but it provides a layer on top of threejs, where you can create your own shaders as well as procedural geometries with a node-based editor.

(disclaimer, I am building it)

Its core library is also open-source, so you could easily extend it if needed.

And you can edit the shaders live from the editor. But by default, when you export a scene, the shaders are not editable via Polygonjs api anymore, only via threejs api. The reason is to make sure the export scene is as optimized as possible. Happy to discuss options if that was something interesting to add.

Comment: Moderator note: I see some users have flagged this answer as spam. Note that the flag reason says "Exists only to promote a product or service, **does not disclose the author's affiliation.**" However, the answer above *does* disclose the author's affiliation with this software/service. The suggestion is also relevant to answering this question. So I don't think this answer merits deletion. I do think the answer could be improved by editing it to explain in more detail *how* to implement these features with this tool.

Comment: thank you. I'm hoping to find the time to add details and code samples.I've also just received a message from the moderators in my inbox, but it is truncated and it looks like I do not have permission to view the full message.

Comment: I don't believe any moderator on GameDev.StackExchange has sent you a moderation message, but I cannot speak for other sites in the network.

Comment: ah, apologies, it was from stackoverflow. I'm still getting my head around the different sites. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.